# socket error using boto with Jython

Tags: python, jython, boto

I'm in the process of porting a project originally done in CPython over to Jython in order to leverage some java libraries. Things seem to be working fine except that for some reason I'm getting errors when trying to connect to s3 with boto:

```
>>> from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
>>> s3 = S3Connection(aws_access_id, aws_secret_key)
>>> s3.get_all_buckets()

  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/jython/Lib/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 384, in
    body = response.read()
  File "/usr/share/jython/Lib/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 411, in rea
    self._cached_response = httplib.HTTPResponse.read(self)
  File "/usr/share/jython/Lib/httplib.py", line 546, in read
    s = self.fp.read()
  File "/usr/share/jython/Lib/httplib.py", line 1296, in read
    return s + self._file.read()
  File "/usr/share/jython/Lib/socket.py", line 1672, in read
    data = self._sock.recv(recv_size)
  File "/usr/share/jython/Lib/socket.py", line 180, in set_last_error
    return method(obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/jython/Lib/socket.py", line 171, in map_exception
    raise _map_exception(jlx)
socket.error: [Errno 104] Software caused connection abort
```

Running the exact same connection code in CPython works perfectly. 
I've tried forcing boto to log debug messages, but they are the exact same between Jython and CPython until the Jython one fails. Has anyone run into this before or have any suggestions for debugging this further?

Running Jython 2.7b1, CPython 2.7.4 on ubuntu.